# rendered entity usage in "add node" form for an entity ref field

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

In one of my "add node" form, I would like to display the 'name' field of referenced content type rather than the title.

Let's say, Content type 'Car' contains a field called 'owner'  which is entity ref to content type 'person'.  'person' has a unique title but also has a field called 'name'.

While displaying to the user '/node/add/car' form, I like to give the user a 'select list' for the field 'owner'.  I want to populate this field with the names of the 'person' nodes in the system and not their 'title'.

So in 'manage form display' of the content type 'car', I used 'select list' and in the 'manage display', selected for the 'owner' field, format of "rendered entity". But this displays only the title in the dropdown list in 'add/node/car'.

When that did not work, I tried using the new d8 feature,'display mode'.  I created a display mode called "nameview" and created a "nameview" display for content type 'person' which displays only the field 'name'.  I then used that view mode in the "manage display" for 'Car'. Still I get only the titles in 'add/node/car'.

What am I doing wrong? or is this a bug in d8?

Answer (score 1):

What you configure in Manage display has nothing to do with what is shown in the form. That's not how it works.

You can do this using a view. In field settings, configure it to use a view show possible values and then configure that view to show the values you want to see.

Comment: But in a view, how do I get user input for the rest of the fields?

Comment: Ajay, I don't understand your comment in the context of your question. Either there's an important part of your requirement missing from your original question, or you've not understood what Berdir means.

Comment: What you need to is this: 1) Create a view with an "entity reference display", showing the "Person" content type and containing just the field "Name" that you want; 2) in the field settings for the entity reference field "owner", choose the Reference method "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" instead of "Default"; 3) select the view you created in step 1 as the reference view to use. You don't need to touch the "manage form display" or "manage display" stuff.

Comment: Thanks Berdir and @Johnathan for clarifying it further.  Now I think I get what I need to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a different error  now .  When I click on Add->"entity reference"  in "Views..edit" to create a new display, It gives a msg "Display "Entity Reference" needs a selected search fields to work properly. See the settings for the Entity Reference list format."  but it does not bring up anything when I click on 'settings'  and there is a message in the log which says "User error: "preview" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() ".  So I guess I am stuck for the moment while I check around to see if there is solution to this.  Thanks again

Comment: @jonathan, does the above procedure work for adding a node?  eg.  "node/add/car" ?  I still do not see the "names"  in the drop down.  I also tried using "autocomplete".

Comment: BTW, I got  past the "User error: "preview" is a ..."  error.  Doing the "+add" from the "views" screen to add a "entity reference" display, gives the error every time.  Just refreshing the cache before setting the search field, I got past that error.

Comment: As I understand it, yes, it works on the node/add form

Comment: Hmm.. It still shows titles in "node/add/car" even though I can change from "select list" to "autocomplete" using "Manage form display" and I have set "Reference Type" to the view I created like you said.   Maybe a bug.  Any thing else I should check?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible with Entity Reference views in Drupal 8, but will be soon. See [View output is not used for autocomplete display](https://www.drupal.org/node/2174633).